# Convolution of measures and stochastic dominance

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Consider two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$, namely $\mu$ and $\nu$. Suppose that $\mu$ stochastically dominates $\nu$ so that $\mu \ge \nu$. Here I am considering the first-order stochastic dominance, i.e.
$$ \mu \ge \nu \iff \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \: \mathrm{d}\mu(x) \ge \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \: \mathrm{d}\nu(x)  $$
for all non decreasing measurable functions $f$.

My question is: does the convolution between measures preserve this ordering? In particular, is the following statement true?
$$ \mu \ge \nu \implies \mu^{*n} \ge \nu^{*n}$$
where $\mu^{*n}=\underbrace{\mu*\mu*\dots*\mu}_{n \text{-times}}$.

I think this is trivial but I don't see how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: Instead of convolution do you actually mean product measure ?

Comment: Nope, I do mean convolution of measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ f $ is a non decreasing measurable functions, then

\begin{align}
&\int f(z)\,(\mu\ast\mu)(\mathrm{d}z)=\mathsf{E}[f(X+Y)]\quad \text{where $X,Y$ are i.i.d. and $X\overset{d}{=}\mu$}\\
&\quad=\int \Biggl[\int f(x+y)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)\Biggr]\mu(\mathrm{d}y)
\qquad \text{For fixed $ y $, $ f(x+y) $ is non decreasing in $ x $ }\\
&\quad\ge \int \Biggl[\int f(x+y)\,\nu(\mathrm{d}x)\Biggr]\mu(\mathrm{d}y)
\qquad\text{ $ g(y)=\int f(x+y)\,\nu(\mathrm{d}x) $ is non decreasing in $ y $ }\\
&\quad\ge \int \Biggl[\int f(x+y)\,\nu(\mathrm{d}x)\Biggr]\nu(\mathrm{d}y)\\
&\quad=\int f(z)\,(\nu\ast\nu)(\mathrm{d}z)
\end{align}